# MASM32 Assembly - Reading a number from Console

Tags: windows, assembly, dos, masm, masm32

Sorry if this question is really simple, but I tried all that I know and coudn't figure it out.

I'm trying to make a simple procedure which takes a string and a Count from the console and print the string number of times specified by the Count.

Everything is fine, but when I mov the Count to eax for a loop, the value get's messed up and I end up with an infinite loop of print.

I tried to change the Count to DWORD with atodw, but didn't work.

here's the code :

```
PrintString PROTO :DWORD, :DWORD

.data

        String db 100 DUP(0)

        Count db 10 DUP(0)

.code
    start:
        ;1- get user input

        invoke StdIn, addr String, 99
        invoke StdIn, addr Count, 10

        ;2- Remove the CRLF from count
         invoke StripLF, addr Count

        ;3- Convert the count to DWORD 
        invoke atodw, addr InputCount
        mov Counter, eax

        ;4- Call the Printer function

        invoke Printer, addr String,   addr Count

Printer PROC StringToPrint:DWORD, count:DWORD         

 mov eax,count  ;;;;;; This is the problem I think

 Looppp:
            push eax

            invoke StdOut,  StringToPrint

            pop eax
            dec eax

            jnz Looppp
    ret
Printer endp
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re passing `addr Count` – the address of the string – as the second argument to `Printer`. But it expects an integer, so you want to pass `Counter` instead.

Since you’re using a language without type checking, adopting a naming convention such as [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for your identifiers could help you see and avoid this kind of problem.  With the variables here named `strCount` and `dwCount`, for example, it would be more obvious that you were using the wrong one.

As an aside, `eax` must eventually reach zero so your printing loop won’t be *infinite* – just rather longer than you intended…

Comment: Thanks a lot, This solved the problem. I'll have a look at the Hungarian Notation, seems much more elegant and efficient.